# Set a max length to OsdComputerName in MDT

Tags: computer-name, mdt

Is their a way to set a max length to the OsdComputername in MDT. By default it's 15 chars, but we need it to have a 8-chars length max.

First time I have a customer who ask this restriction...

I guess it's possible, but I can't find any workaround.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MDT does not have such a restriction by default. You would need to build another form  and execute it before Litetouch.wsf to request the input of the osdcomputername, then use a "userexitscript" to inject that value as an MDT variable.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.